# C# Regex: Replace whitespace into XML tag

Tags: c#, regex, xml

I'm looking for a regex to replace whitespaces INTO an XML tag.
For exemple:

```
<TAG 1>bla bla bla</TAG 1>
```

replace to:

```
<TAG1>bla bla bla</TAG1>
```

I wrote this:

```cs
string currentLine = Regex.Replace(currentLine,
@"(?<=\</?\S*)\s+(?=\S*\>)", String.Empty);
```

but it's not working, because it's remove between 2 tag also...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/YL2iPP/1

Answer (score 1):

You should bear in mind that `\S` matches *any* non-whitespace character, that is why in case some text is glued to `<` or `>` you may match spaces outside of angle brackets.

You can use

```cs
var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=<[^<>]*)\s(?=[^<>]*>)", "");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%3c%5b%5e%3c%3e%5d*%29%5cs%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%3c%3e%5d*%3e%29&i=%3cTAG+1%3ebla+bla+bla%3c%2fTAG+1%3e%3cT+A+++G+1%3ebla+bla+bla%3c%2fT++++AG+1%3e&r=). Details:

- `(?<=<[^<>]*)` - a location immediately preceded with `<` and then any zero or more chars other than `<` and `>`
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(?=[^<>]*>)` - a location immediately followed with any zero or more chars other than `<` and `>` and then a `>`.

Comment: Good, +1, but it's noteworthy that this assumes that there are no XML attributes.